# Tracking User Actions on Landing Pages in Django

Tags: django, django-apps

I'm developing a web application. It's months away from completion but I would like to build a landing page to show to potential customers to explain things and gauge their interest--basically collecting their email address and if they feel like it additional information like names + addresses.

Because I'm already using Django to build my site I thought I might use another Django App to serve as this landing page. The features I need are

- to display a fairly static page and potentially a series of pages,
- collect emails (and additional customer data)
- track their actions--*e.g., they got through the first two pages but didnt fill out the final page.*

Is there any pre-existing Django app that provides any of these features?

---

If there is not a Django app, then does anyone know of another, faster/better way than building my own app? Perhaps a pre-existing web service that you can skin and make look like your own? Maybe there's the perfect system but it's PHP?--I'm open for whatever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1: Google Sites**

You can set it up very very quickly. Though your monitoring wouldn't be as detailed as you're asking for.. Still, easy and fasssst!

**Option 2: bbclone**

Something else that may be helpful is to set up some PHP based site (wordpress or something) and use bbclone for tracking stuff on it. I've found bbclone to be pretty intense with the reporting what everyone does - though it's been a while since I used it.

**Option 3: Django Flatpages**

The flatpages Django contrib app is pretty handy for making static flat pages. I'd probably just embed a Google Docs Form to collect email addresses (as that's super fast and lets you get back to real work). But this suggestion would still leave you needing to figure out how to get the level of detail you want on the stats end.

**Perhaps consider Google Analytics anyway?**

Regardless, I suggest you use Google Analytics with everything. That'll work with anything you do really, and for all I know, perhaps you can find a way to get the stats you're really looking for out of it.